# Is there a way to get a parametric solution to matrix using matrix solver from some lin. algebra java library?

Tags: java, matrix, linear-algebra, equation-solving, parametric-equations

All the matrix solvers I've come across require the matrices to be square and invertible, but what about matrices that are not square and have multiple solutions...how would I go about finding a parametric form of this using java?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the [SVD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition) of your matrix